# How to update Sqlmap with git?

Tags: git, sqlmap

I'm try to update my sqlmap in the Linux. But I get the error like this :

> error pathspec did not match any file s known to git.

I'm just a freshman, and I am not too familiar with Git. 
How can I get past this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the exact git command you are using.

For instance, if you checkout a branch you have not yet fetched from your remote repo, try `git fetch` first.
Then `git checkout yourBranch`: if `origin/yourBranch` exists, it will work.

If you checkout a file, pay attention to the case: it can be case-sensitive.

> I can't checkout .fatal : You are on a branch yet to be born .

Make sure you have added and make at least one commit.

```
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Comment: i have tryed the git fetch it success , but i can't checkout .fatal : You are on a branch yet to be born .

Comment: But I got a new Error : From git github com sqlmapproject sqlmap branch HEAD FETCH_HEAD fatal refusing to merge unrelated histories'  T T.

Comment: @J.Joe Then clone again your GitHub repo, and try again to add and commit your modification in the new cloned repo

Answer (score 0):

**is git**

```
git add 
git commit -m
```

**is not git   Direct**

```
sqlmap --update
```